# python del is deleting wrong line in txt after using loop

Tags: python, text

I am trying to del 'line1', 'line4' and 'line5' in list. But the result come out is not what I expect.

```
item =  ['line1',
'line2',
'line3',
'line4',
'line5',
'line6',
'line7',
'line8']

removeLine = [0,1,3,5]

for x, y in grouped(sorted(removeLine), 2):
    print x,y
    del item[x:y]

print item

>>> ['line2', 'line3', 'line4', 'line7', 'line8']
```

but my expected result is

```
>>> ['line2', 'line3', 'line7', 'line8']
```

hopefully someone can give me some advise. thank you very much.

Comment: After you've deleted lines 9 and 10, the lines that were at 15 and 16 are *obviously no longer there* - they moved up due to the previous deletion!  You need to process the deletion ranges in *descending* order, so that they don't affect any of the following deletions.

Comment: @jasonharper or account for them moving forward, but going backwards seems more elegant (which is a funny thought).

Comment: In the future, try to provide a [mcve]. It is required for debugging questions, and anyway, usually the process of creating such an example provides insight and you might answer your own question.

Comment: hi @jasonharper , i already modify my question. In your first comment, you are mention about deletion ranges in descending order. I will your way later, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: thank you very much @jasonharper your deletion ranges in descending order is worked in my case, really appreciate for your advise.

Comment: @Coleone, There is not line 0 ? Assuming you mean indexes in `remove_line` i have answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can make use of the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html) function to achieve this:

```
my_list = ['0','1','2','3','4','5']
index_to_delete = [0,3,4]

for i,j in enumerate(index_to_delete): #Groups indices with numbers
    del my_list[j-i] #After every deletion i increases to account for lost index
>>>print(my_list)
['1', '2', '5']
```

From this you get the general idea that you need to keep track of deletion as well. So, after every deletion, the index to be deleted is to be reduced to cope up with the deletion.

*This can be done in many ways, using `enumerate` seems to be the lightest case for me, i didn't modify my code to do your job as it's left for you to implement because now you have the general idea of doing it.*